# Issue with saving multiple plots by name

Tags: r

I'm trying to save a large amount of plots with a loop.

The first step is the creation of plots via a dlply function that is working great. It results in a large amount of graph stocked in "p".
For this example, p has a length of 715, so the loop is supposed to print and save me the 715 plots i want in png format.
Except it is saving only 115 of them!

In the following code i am renaming the files i want by pasting character strings (SITE+ SP).

```
for( i in 1:length(p)){
filename<-paste(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE2[i],"_",SUBTOT_DATE$SP2[i], ".png", sep="")
png(file=filename)
print(p[i])
dev.off()}
```

It is working fine (all the plots are printed as the console shows them all) but it is saving only 115 plots. I find out that if i rename the plot files with a number (as the following code shows, example Plot IA_1), it prints the good amount of plots.

```
for( i in 1:length(p)){
filename<-paste("plot IA","_",i, ".png", sep="")
png(file=filename)
print(p[i])
dev.off()}
```

So the problem comes from the name of files, but i don't get what is limiting the number of plot saved since i can find at least one of each "SITE2" plot, and that there is no great difference between the "SP2" strings (I mean no special character or length difference, just alphabetical characters). Here is some of the SP2:

```
[1] Aglais io                                        
[2] Aglais urticae                                   
[3] Anthocharis cardamines                           
[4] Apatura ilia                                     
[5] Aphantopus hyperantus                            
[6] Aporia crataegi                                  
[7] Araschnia levana                                 
[8] Argynnis adippe                                  
[9] Argynnis aglaja                                  
[10] Argynnis paphia                                  
[11] Aricia agestis                                   
[12] Boloria dia ---------It stops here                                  
[13] Boloria euphrosyne                               
[14] Brenthis daphne                                  
[15] Brintesia circe                                  
[16] Callophrys rubi                                  
[17] Carterocephalus palaemon
```

Is there a sort of limitation i'm not aware of ? For information, SITE2 and SP2 are both factors.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: 
I did more tests and it appears that it is working fine if i only use one of the two names i want. For some reason, when i use both SUBTOT_DATE$SITE2[i] and SUBTOT_DATE$SP2[i], it doesnt work anymore.
The names don't reach the limit of characters accepted for a file name in windows (260).

EDIT2:

It is working when i add a number before the filename, which is acceptable for my task. It seems to be a overwriting issue, although my dataset doesnt get any doubles. This isn't a proper solution to my issue, but could help peaople encountering the same issues that i did.

Comment: Can you make your problem reproducible? Can you put the `print` statement outside the png-dev.off chunk?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that one plot needs a lot of rows, and reaching the point where it stop saving files would take thousands of rows. Plus, i can't reproduce something i dont understand, see my Edit for more info.

Comment: Are all combination of SITE2 and SP2 unique ? What is `length(unique( paste0(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE2,"_",SUBTOT_DATE$SP2) ))` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the combination of SITE2 and SP2 are not unique. It means that all your plots are plotted but some are saved in an already existing pdf files and erase the previous plot.

If `length(unique( paste0(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE2,"_",SUBTOT_DATE$SP2) ))` = 115, then it was your problem.

Comment: Hi, no it is 715. As i said in my second edit, i found another way to solve my problem. Thanks anyway!